# Why ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id create files with incorrect permissions

Tags: ssh, freebsd, file-permissions, truenas, ssh-keygen

I have a FreeBSD host (sh) that I just set up last week, and it is doing these two weird things that seem to be related:

1. ssh-keygen ON this host is creating both private and pub keys with 775 file permissions
2. ssh-copy-id TO this host is creating authorized_keys with 775 permissions

The result here is SSHd won't use these files in authentications until the permissions are fixed.  A problem I'd like to get to the bottom of because I wanted to set this host up to be a bastion/jump server in the end.

I have illustrated each here with some notes below.

When I `chmod` these files to the correct permissions, everything works as expected.  I guess the ultimate question is **why does this one host write files with incorrect permissions?**

I would be very obliged for any observations or insights as to what the deal is here.  I have read the ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id  manual pages and did not see any option to either specify the output file's permissions or to use a config file to specify it.

#### Issue #1

Here I will create a new key pair and reveal the resulting permissions:

```
jg@sh ~ ❯❯❯ ssh-keygen -C testkey -f ~/.ssh/test-key
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/jg/.ssh/test-key
Your public key has been saved in /home/jg/.ssh/test-key.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:dSQXsohvg53uRy07TWZ/kA7DP251L6MSA5tonxXd0zQ testkey
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|          o +.   |
|       . . *   E.|
|      . . o... o.|
|       +.o... o .|
|      ..S+ +   o |
|      ooo.* O o o|
|     . ..+ X * oo|
|       .o = . O o|
|        .. o.+.= |
+----[SHA256]-----+
jg@sh ~ ❯❯❯ ll .ssh/test-key*
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jg  jg   2.5K Dec 12 15:38 .ssh/test-key
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jg  jg   561B Dec 12 15:38 .ssh/test-key.pub
```

#### Issue #2

Start by removing the existing `authorized_keys` file:

```
jg@sh ~ ❯❯❯ rm -rf .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Hop on another host and use `ssh-copy-id` to put a public key on this host:

```
jg@BTFU:~ % ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa_btfu-to-sh_20231212 jg@sh
(jg@sh.thirtynineohsix) Password for jg@sh:
```

Get back on our target host and check out that file:

```
jg@sh ~ ❯❯❯ ll .ssh/authorized_keys
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 jg  jg   573B Dec 12 15:41 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

### Notes:

- This system is FreeBSD 13.2-release-p5 and runs as a jail on TrueNAS appliance (if that matters).
- I believe this is unlikely to be a FreeBSD issue, other jails of the same version on the same appliance behave normally, writing private keys with 600, public keys with 644 permissions, and authorized_hosts with 600 permissions
- $HOME is owned by jg and is 755 (`drwxr-xr-x+`) -- that appears correct.
- the umask for the jg user is 022, which also seems correct

Comment: The `+` on `ls -l` means your files have ACLs, which override the basic/traditional permission bits. Look at `getfacl ~/.ssh/*` and also `~/.ssh ~` to see if/how they were inherited. (And Happy New Year.)

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085 !  This was hint that put me on the path to success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @dave_thompson_085 I was able to figure this out, so leaving a trail of pointers for any intrepid explorer who comes along behind.

#1 most important, I missed the `+` in the file listing as it carries meaning. It means the file has an ACL.  This is called out in the manpage for `ls`.

#2 FreeBSD uses NFSv4 file ACLs which are different from the POSIX ACLs that Linux platforms use.

#3 Use `getfacl [filename]` to see what's applied.  Read the setfacl(1) manpage to resolve what the output means.

#4 When you get to this point, you may squint at the setfacl(1) manpage for a while and try to concoct a `setfacl -m` (modify) command, and you might get an error similar to:
`setfacl: [filename]: branding mismatch; existing ACL is NFSv4, entry to be merged is POSIX.1e`

#5 You might eventually just want to remove the ACL entirely!  To do this use `setfacl -b [filename|*]` and `setfacl -b .` to remove the ACL from the desired file(s) and the directory so new files will not inherit the ACL.

(If you have a better way to *change* the file's ACL and the ACL on the directory so new files inherit permissions correctly, I would love it if you dropped some knowledge on me with a comment or answer here.)

That it is TrueNAS/FreeNAS specifically doesn't actually matter but it does imply the filesystem of the jail is ZFS, doubles down on point #2 above.

Answer (score 1):

ssh-keygen on FreeBSD uses umask only for `test-key.pub`, umask it not used for `test-key`.

The effective permissions looks like the HOME is on a share (maybe samba) which forces the filemode to differ (create mask = 0775)